# Django form.is_valid() always false

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm coding a login. When I programmed the form by hand I got it working.

The code below works:

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'app/login.htm')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('error'))
        if not user.is_active:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('error'))

        # Correct password, and the user is marked "active"
        auth.login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login'  %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></p>

    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />
</form>
```

Great! But now I want to do the same thing using Django's forms.

The code below is not working because I get is_valid() == False, always.

views.py:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        print form.is_valid(), form.errors, type(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            ## some code....
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('error'))
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'app/login.htm', {'form':form})
```

template:

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

There are a bunch of people on stackoverflow complaining that they get is_valid always false. I have read all those posts, and as far as I can tell I'm not making any of those mistakes. I found a new mistake to make :-)

EDIT: I added a print in the code. The output when opening the login view and submitting is

```
[27/Dec/2013 14:01:35] "GET /app/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 910
False  <class 'django.forms.util.ErrorDict'>
[27/Dec/2013 14:01:38] "POST /app/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 910
```

and so is_valid() is False, but form.errors is empty.

Comment: Why are you redirecting away in case of error? If you didn't do that, the form would be rerendered with the error messages, and you'd be able to see exactly why the form is invalid. Remove the first else clause completely.

Comment: I removed the first else clause like you said, and after submitting, the form is just rerendered again, cleared.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out that Maxime was right after all (sorry) - you do need the `data` parameter:

```
form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
```

The reason for that, though, is that AuthenticationForm overwrites the signature of `__init__` to expect the *request* as the first positional parameter. If you explicitly supply `data` as a kwarg, it will work.

(You should still leave out the else clause that redirects away on error, though: it's best practice to let the form re-render itself with errors in that case.)

Comment: Right you are, that fixed it. Can you walk me thru the thought process that led you to that conclusion? You know, something about teaching a man how to fish...

Comment: I looked at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L157). Although if I was on a computer with a Python shell at the moment I would have just imported the class there and done `help(AuthenticationForm)`, which would have given me the signature.

Comment: you know, now I often go read the source code... :-) It's been almost 3 years. Geez.

Answer (score 12):

Check out `form.errors` which will help you find out why.

Comment: Yeah, in other similar questions people said that. I tried it, and form.errors is empty. It's an object of type django.forms.util.ErrorDict, but contains nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If situation arises, that you don't have an option (I was trying to work with bootstrap modals and it was just not working), I had to do this, or else the modal would always trigger even if the form had not issues (**and the is_valid is always False by default**)

**What I needed:**

- Show modal when I click a button
- if errors, show on the same page, the modal, with the error.

**In the modal template:**

```
{% if not brand_form.is_valid and brand_form.errors %}
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(window).on('load', (function() {
                $('#brandAddModal').modal('show');
             }));
        </script>
                    
          {{ brand_form.non_field_errors }}
{% endif %}
```

**In the view:**

```
def add_brand_form(request):
    form = BrandForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BrandForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
        else:
            return render(request, template_name='home.html', context={'brand_form':form})
        
    return render(request, template_name='modal_add_brand.html', context={'brand_form':form})
```